# Recursively finding indexes of an INT in an ever-shrinking LispList

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, lisp

2nd-year Computer-Science student here, and as part of a set of exercises on recursion, we've been given some arbitrary problems to solve with LispLists.  I'm stuck half-way through, so if anyone can point me in the right direction without explicitly giving me the answer, that would be great.

I need to find the positions of every instance of ***intToFind*** in the LispList ***listToCheck*** - the only conditions are that:

- no additional arguments can be used
- it has to be done recursively

For everyone who hasn't encountered LispLists - they don't have indexing, and the only methods you can call on them are:

- **.isEmpty()** *returns boolean*
- **.head()** *returns the element at the 0th position*
- **.tail()** *returns a LispList of all elements that aren't the head*
- **.cons(value)** *adds value to the 'head' position - shifting everything else one down*

There's also one method I wrote previously called:

- ***recursiveCountLength(list)***  *returns an int of the length of the passed LispList.*

The list I've been testing on is: *[2,3,4,2,5,12,2,5]*, so the result I'm looking for is *[0,3,6]* - with that out the way, here's what I've got so far (explanation of what I'm attempting after):

```
public static LispList<Integer>
  recursivePositions(LispList<Integer> listToCheck, int intToFind)
{
  if(listToCheck.isEmpty()) return listToCheck;
  else {
    // go through the array in its entirety once through,
    // do everything else 'on the way back up'
    LispList<Integer> positions = recursivePositions(listToCheck.tail(), intToFind);

    //get the current length and current head
    int currentInt      = listToCheck.head();
    int currentLength   = recursiveCountLength(listToCheck); 

    //if a match is found, add the current length of the list to the list 
    if(currentInt == intToFind) return positions.cons(currentLength);
    else return positions;
  }
}
```

My current theory is that length of the array at each encounter of the int we're looking for (in this case 2) subtracted from the original length of the list (in this case 8) will give us the indexes.

- **2** first happens with a length of 8 (8-8 = index of 0, so indexes now [0]),
- **2** next happens with a length of 5 (8-5 = index of 3, so indexes now [0, 3]),
- **2** lastly happens at a length of 2 (8-2 = index of 6, so indexes now [0, 3, 6]).

The only problem is that I can't figure out how to get a static '8' - which leaves me to conclude that I'm approaching this in entirely the wrong way.  Does anyone have any tips for me here?  Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: That method you wrote is effectively "an additional argument", just implemented as a function rather than a depth tracking integer. Are you allowed to use it? Are you *supposed* to use it?

Comment: You get a list of positions back. For each recursive step, I would update this returned list. It's not how it would be written in 'real' Lisp, but in some kind of 'pure' Lisp...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify: a `LispList` is just a singly-linked-list (to differentiate from a Java `LinkedList`, which is double-linked).

Usually, you'd use a helper that carries information into the recursive calls, such as the current position and the positions already found (the current partial result).

```
LispList<Integer> positions (final int item, final LispList<Integer> list) {
    return positionsAux( item, list, 0, new LispList<Integer>() );
}

private LispList<Integer> positionsAux (final int item,
                                        final LispList<Integer> list,
                                        final int position,
                                        final LispList<Integer> result) {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return result.reverse();
    }
    if (list.head().intValue() == item) {
        result = result.cons(position);
    }
    return positionsAux( item, list.tail(), position + 1, result );
}
```

If that is not allowed, you need to carry the results backwards.  If you assume that the recursive call has returned the correct result for your `list.tail()`, you need to add 1 to each found position to get the right result for your `list`.  Then, you `cons` a 0 to the result if the current element matches.  This version is less efficient than the first, because you traverse the current result list for every element of the input list (so it is *O(n·m)* instead of *O(n)*, where *n* is the length of the input list and *m* the length of the result list).

```
LispList<Integer> positions (final int item, final LispList<Integer> list) {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return new LispList<Integer>();
    }
    final LispList<Integer> tailResult = positions( item, list.tail() );
    final LispList<Integer> result = tailResult.addToEach( 1 );
    if (list.head().intValue() == item) {
        return result.cons( 0 );
    } else {
        return result;
    }
}
```

Implementing `reverse()` for the first version and `addToEach(int)` for the second is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least 3 arguments. Pretty sure adding more arguments is okay since he allows helper methods (because otherwise you could just make your method call the helper method which has more arguments).

Simplest way recursively:

```
public static LispList<Integer> positions(LispList<Integer> list, Integer key, Integer position){
    if (list.isEmpty()) return  LispList.empty();

    if (list.head().equals(key)) return positions(list.tail(), key, position+1).cons(position);

    return positions(list.tail(), key, position+1);
}
```